# How can I update the value of a cookie in ASP.NET MVC 5 app?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, cookies, asp.net-mvc-5, httpcookie

I have an app that is written using c# on the top of ASP.NET MVC 5 framework.

I have a need to create, get and update existing cookie. So I created the following class which allows me to easily interact with the cookies.

Here is my class

```
public class CookieJar : ICookie
{
    // Total minutes to define forever. 525600 is the total minutes in 1 year.
    protected const int foreverMinutes = 525600;

    protected HttpContextBase Context { get; private set; }

    public CookieJar(HttpContextBase context)
    {
        Context = context;
    }

    public HttpCookie Create(string name, dynamic value, int? minutes = null, string path = null, string domain = null, bool isSecure = false, bool isHttpOnly = true)
    {

        HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(name);
        cookie.Value = (value == null) ? null : value.ToString();
        if (minutes.HasValue)
        {
            cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(minutes.Value);
        }

        cookie.Path = path;
        cookie.Domain = domain;
        cookie.Secure = isSecure;
        cookie.HttpOnly = isHttpOnly;

        Context.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);

        return cookie;
    }

    public HttpCookie Forever(string name, dynamic value, string path = null, string domain = null, bool isSecure = false, bool isHttpOnly = true)
    {
        return Create(name, value, foreverMinutes, path, domain, isSecure, isHttpOnly);
    }

    public HttpCookie Forget(string name, string path = null, string domain = null)
    {
        var cookie = Get(name);

        if (cookie != null)
        {
            cookie.Value = null;
            cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
            Context.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
        }

        return cookie;
    }

    public bool Has(string name)
    {
        return Context.Request.Cookies.AllKeys.Contains(name);
    }

    public HttpCookie Get(string name, dynamic defaultValue = null)
    {
        if (Has(name))
        {
            return Context.Request.Cookies[name];
        }

        if (defaultValue != null)
        {
            return Create(name, defaultValue);
        }

        return null;
    }

    public void Set(string name, dynamic value)
    {
        var cookie = Context.Response.Cookies.Get(name);
        if (cookie == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        cookie.Value = (value == null) ? null : value.ToString();
        Context.Response.Cookies.Set(cookie);
    }
}
```

The problem happens when I create a cookie for a specific path, and then trying to update its value. When trying to update the value, from some reason the Path changes to "/" instead of whatever path the cookie was created with.

Here are screen shots of what I have going on

This screenshot is from the `Create` method, as you can see I provide a path for the cookie
[image]

Since the cookie already exists, I want to only update the `Value` of it leaving everything else the same. Here is a screenshot from the `Set` method, as you can see the value of the path is different than what I originally created.

[image]

Here is a simple use case where I use this class from a controller

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ICookie Cookie { get; set; }
    public HomeController(ICookie cookie)
    {
        Cookie = cookie;
    }

    public ActionResult Get(int id)
    {
        var cookiePath = string.Format("/Home/Get/{0}", id);

        Cookie.Create("SomeKey", "SomeValue", null, cookiePath);
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Get(ViewModel model)
    {
        Cookie.Set("SomeKey", "SomeUpdateValue");

        return View();
    }
}
```

My immediate workaround is to create a cookie every-time rather than using `Set`.

How can I correctly update the value of the cookie while leaving everything else the same?

Comment: That's because browser does not send any cookie metadata. All it sends is list of cookie names and values. No path, no expiration time. Since you use request cookies for update - they cannot contain original path by design.

Comment: @Evk  so the only way here is to create a new cookie each time to override existing one?

Comment: Yes that's the only way (not related to asp net, just because of how http cookies work).